# Change guild name and picture in discord.js?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to edit my server in discord.js so as soon as I enter a command, it overwrites the name and icon. This is my code:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const guild = new Discord.Guild();
const { prefix, token } = require('./config.json');

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready to launch!');
});

client.login(token);

guild.setIcon('./icon.png');
guild.setName('Guild name');
```

If anyone could help and explain why I'm getting loads of error messages, that'd be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using an existing guild to overwrite name and icon in. Also you are trying to use the api before it has been initialised.

`client.login(token);` returns a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). Therefore you can't know if the statements below will execute with the api already initialised or not. That's why you should listen for an event. As you did with the `ready`.

Especially a [`message`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message) event if you want to implement commands.

```js
client.on("message", async (message) => {
    if (message.content == "editguild") {
        try {
            await message.guild.setIcon("./icon.png");
            await message.guild.setName("Guild name");
            message.channel.send("Successfully changed guild name and icon.");
        } catch {
            message.channel.send("There was an error setting the guild name and icon!");
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been using this one:

```
client.on("message", async (message) => {
if(message.content.startsWith(";setguildicon")) {
  if (!message.guild.me.permissions.has('MANAGE_SERVER')) { 
    const perms = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle(`Bot missing permissions`)
    .setColor(`2f3136`)
    .setDescription(`I need **MANAGE_SERVER** permission in order to change the server's icon!`)
    message.lineReplyNoMention(perms)
   }
  if (!message.member.hasPermission(['ADMINISTRATOR'])) {
    const missingperms = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle(`Missing permissions`)
    .setColor(`2f3136`)
     .setDescription("> **ADMINISTRATOR** permission requiered to change the server icon!");
     message.lineReplyNoMention(missingperms)
} else {
   args = message.content.split(" ").slice(1);
             var argresult = args.join(' ');
             if(argresult) {
               message.channel.send(`Guild icon changed. If it didn't, something may be wrong with the permissions or image link!`)
              message.guild.setIcon(
                `${argresult}`
              ).catch(error => { 
                console.log(`error`) 
              })
 } else {
   const missingargs = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
.setTitle(`Missing arguments`)
.setDescription(`\`;setguildicon [image link]\``)
.setColor(`2f3136`)
message.lineReplyNoMention(missingargs)
 }
}
}
if(message.content.startsWith(";setguildname")) {
  if (!message.guild.me.permissions.has('MANAGE_SERVER')) { 
    const perms = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle(`Bot missing permissions`)
    .setColor(`2f3136`)
    .setDescription(`I need **MANAGE_SERVER** permission in order to change the server's name!`)
    message.lineReplyNoMention(perms)
   }
  if (!message.member.hasPermission(['ADMINISTRATOR'])) {
    const missingperms = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle(`Missing permissions`)
    .setColor(`2f3136`)
     .setDescription("> **ADMINISTRATOR** permission requiered to change the server name!");
     message.lineReplyNoMention(missingperms)
} else {
   args = message.content.split(" ").slice(1);
             var argresult = args.join(' ');
             if(argresult) {
               message.channel.send(`Guild name changed. If it didn't, something may be wrong with the permissions or the name!`)
              message.guild.setName(
                `${argresult}`
              ).catch(error => { 
                console.log(`error`) 
              })
 } else {
   const missingargs = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
.setTitle(`Missing arguments`)
.setDescription(`\`;setguildname [name]\``)
.setColor(`2f3136`)
message.lineReplyNoMention(missingargs)
 }
}
}
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).